# Translate Animation based on screen size

Tags: java, android, animation, screen-size, translate-animation

I am using the following translate animation to move an image vertically down onto the screen in my android app. However, currently it goes to a fixed position of 150. I would like this value to be dependent on the screen size. For example, I want the image to stop at 20% of the users screen length, starting from the top of the screen. How would I adjust the y delta value to accomodate this?

```
    mScanner = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo_img);

    mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -300, 150);
    mAnimation.setDuration(2500);
    mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    //mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
   // mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    mScanner.setAnimation(mAnimation);
    mScanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the device screen lenght (height):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

And now for 20%, set the animation like this:

```
mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -300, height*2/10);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could get the user's screen size programatically using [Get Size](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29)

This Question deals with just that : [Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels)

You would then replace 150 by whatever variable you define the size to be.